# Is $Z/mZ\otimes Z \cong Z/mZ$?

Tags: modules, homological-algebra, tensor-products

I'm reading a Homological Algebra book that states this in some point without proving. I was trying to prove it and it seems to me that the first module is infinite and the second is not.

Comment: $[a]\otimes b = [a b] \otimes 1 \mapsto [a b]$ and inverse is


$[a] \mapsto [a]\otimes 1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: show that every element of $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\otimes\mathbb{Z}$ is equal to one of the form $[k]\otimes 1$ for some $k\in\{0, . . . , m-1\}$.

It will be enough to show this for elements of the form $[x]\otimes y$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following maps:
$$\phi:x\mapsto x\otimes 1:\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z\otimes\mathbb Z$$
and
$$\psi:(a+m\mathbb Z,b)\mapsto ab+m\mathbb Z:\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$$

Then $\psi$ is $\mathbb Z$-bilinear, hence induces a abelian group homomorphism $\bar\psi:\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z\otimes\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$.
A direct computation shows $\phi=\bar\psi^{-1}$.

More generally, for every abelian group $M$ you have a natural isomorphism  of abelian groups $M\otimes\mathbb Z\cong M$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because $\mathbb{Z}$ is the initial ring, so using that tensor products of rings agree with coproducts, we have:

$$\mathbb{Z} \otimes R \cong \mathbb{Z} \sqcup R \cong R$$

for an arbitrary ring $R$.